# how to convert object type to int c++

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, integer

I am trying to create a sort of record list using two classes. One class is for entering the values while other class is for gathering them, organizing them, and printing them. Here is my code:

```
   class enterrecords
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    string birthmonth;

    enterrecords() 
    {
        name = "";
        age = 0;
        birthmonth = "";
    }
    enterrecords(string n, int a, string b) 
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
        birthmonth = b;
    }

};
class records 
{
public:
    vector <enterrecords> list;
    records() 
    {

    }
    records(enterrecords s) 
    {

    }
    void addtolist(const enterrecords s)
    {
        this->list.push_back(s);
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (const auto& it : this->list)
        {
            cout << it.name << " " << it.age << " " << it.birthmonth << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main() 
{
    enterrecords s1;
    enterrecords s2;
    enterrecords s3;
    records c1;
    s1 = enterrecords("john", 21, "jan");
    s2 = enterrecords("male", 25, "feb");
    s3 = enterrecords("rob", 23, "oct");
    c1.addtolist(s1);
    c1.addtolist(s2);
    c1.addtolist(s3);
    c1.print();
}
```

Here is the output of this program:

john 21 jan

male 25 feb

rob 23 oct

ultimately, I want to be able to organize this list by age from youngest to oldest. so after rearranging them, here is what it would look like after:

john 21 jan

rob 23 oct

male 25 feb

I tried to conventionally sort them, but the problem is, "21" "23" and "25" are not int values but object values. Is there any way to convert them into int so that I could do some operations and sort them? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "object values". `enterrecords::age` is an int. To sort your vector by age, use `std::sort` with a comparator that accepts references to two `enterrecords` objects and returns true if the first age is less than the second.

Comment: thank you sir is there any way this could be demonstrated through code?

Answer (score 1):

[std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is normally used to sort a sequence of objects. Either the class has a natural order and then you make an operator< function for it (and preferably also the other boolean comparison operators) or else you pass a comparator function to std::sort that can be a lambda for simple comparisons like comparing one or two member-variables.

Example based on your code (not compiled/tested) that doesn't take the month into account, because you made it a bit more difficult for an example:

```
std::sort(c1.list.begin(), c1.list.end(), [](const auto& r1, const auto& r2) { return r1.age < r2.age; });
```

Comment: so if I used this it will rearrange the list itself or it will only say either r1.age < r1.age is true or not?

Comment: The sort function uses the comparator to order the list. The comparator needs to return true if r1 is less than r2, false otherwise.

Comment: See the linked std::sort page for more information.